# EF core use dbContext.Database.Migrate(); to execute migrations automatically after configuring UseSqlServer()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created an extension method called *AddSQLServer* that is used in the **Startup.cs / ConfigureServices** that simply adds the *dbContext* to the ServiceCollection.
I would like to run the migrations directly after initializing the *dbContext*.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Test");

    services.AddLogging(config =>
    {
         config.AddSqlServer(connectionString);
    }); 
}
```

Action method which configures the dbContext

```
public class MyProvider
{
     private readonly IServiceCollection serviceCollection;

     public MyProvider(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
     {
         this.serviceCollection = serviceCollection;
     }

     public void AddSqlServer(string connectionString)
     {
         serviceCollection.AddDbContext<OutputDbContext>(config => config.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
         // somehow calling dbContext.Database.Migrate(); to run migrations 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to run migrations when configuring services.

You need to use `HostedService` for that and register it in `Program.cs` before registering your startup. That way your migrations will be run by ASP.NET Core MVC engine before starting your application. It guarantees that when your application will be started all your migrations will be applied.

`Program.cs` will look something like this:

```
var host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureServices(service =>
{
    service.AddHostedService<HostedDbMigrationService>();
})
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(x =>
{
    x.UseStartup<Startup>();
}).Build();
```

And create HostedDbMigrationService:

```
public class HostedDbMigrationService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IDbContext _dbContext;

    public HostedDbMigrationService(IDbContext context)
    {
        _dbContext = context;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _dbContext.Database.Migrate();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

In constructor you can access any registered dependencies. In `StartAsync` you can execute your migrations

Comment: Maybe a bit of an overkill to have a whole hosted service for this, but I suppose it will work.

Comment: Hosted services are meant to do such things. Execute migrations, subscribe to events, start scheduler tasks, etc. this is a right way. Startup class should be only used for registering dependencies and shouldn't contain any logic on start of the application